# Ruby: how to save file to UTF-16 Little Endian

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, utf-16le

I want to save ® into a txt file with UTF-16 Little Endian, I tested in some ways

1.The encoding below is UTF-8

> ```
> $RegisterMark=[174].pack('U*')
> file = File.new("C:/Output.txt","w")
> file.puts $RegisterMark
> file.close
> ```

2.The encoding below is UTF-16 Big Endian

> ```
> require 'iconv'
>
> $RegisterMark=[174].pack('U*')
> $utf16RegisterMark =Iconv.conv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $RegisterMark )
> file = File.new("C:/Output.txt","w")
> file.puts $utf16RegisterMark 
> file.close
> ```

The mentod Iconv.conv doesn't suport UTF-16 LE type.

How can I save output.txt with UTF16 LE?

Comment: Are you *sure* it doesn't support `UTF-16LE`?  There are a lot of [examples on the web](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/140946) featuring ruby/iconv conversions to and from `UTF-16LE`...

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to just open the file as UTF-16LE in the first place:

```
register_mark = "\00ua3" # or even just: register_mark = ®

File.open('C:/Output.txt', 'wt', encoding: 'UTF-16LE') do |f|
  f.puts register_mark
end
```

The important bit here is to explicitly specify the encoding of the file, using the `:encoding` key in the `options` `Hash` of the `File.new` method (or in this case, `File.open`). That way, strings written to the file will be converted automatically, no matter what encoding they are in.

I also took the liberty of changing your code to a more idiomatic Ruby style:

- The Ruby community uses `snake_case`, not `CamelCase` for variable and method names.
- Global variables should be avoided, especially since in your example, they are totally superfluous anyway.
- There's really no need to use `Array#pack` here, just write down what you want.
- Whenever possible, use the block form of `File.open`, which will take care of closing the file for you, even in the case of an error or exception.
- When dealing with text files, you should always pass the `t` modifier. It doesn't make any difference on most operating systems (which is why, unfortunately, most Rubyists forget to pass it), but it is *crucial* on Windows, which is what you appear to be using.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat hacky, but this worked for me. Specifically, I was trying to get ruby to output UTF-16LE w/ BOM

```
## Adds BOM, albeit in a somewhat hacky way.
new_html_file = File.open(foo.txt, "w:UTF-8")
new_html_file << "\xFF\xFE".force_encoding('utf-16le') + some_text.force_encoding('utf-8').encode('utf-16le')
```